# Hadoop Data Set Map Reduce DataJoin

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, inner-join

**Code**

I tried to run DataJoin example of Hadoop in Action Book.

```
import java.io.DataInput;
import java.io.DataOutput;
import java.io.IOException;
// import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
// import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.GenericOptionsParser;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.Tool;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Writable;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configured;
import org.apache.hadoop.contrib.utils.join.*;


public class MultiDataSetJoinMR extends Configured implements Tool
{
    public static class MapClass extends DataJoinMapperBase
    {
        protected Text generateInputTag(String inputFile)
        {
            String datasource = inputFile.split("-")[0];
            return new Text(datasource);
        }
        protected Text generateGroupKey(TaggedMapOutput aRecord)
        {
            String line = ((Text) aRecord.getData()).toString();
            String[] tokens = line.split(",");
            String groupKey = tokens[0];
            return new Text(groupKey);
        }
        protected TaggedMapOutput generateTaggedMapOutput(Object value)
        {
            TaggedWritable retv = new TaggedWritable((Text) value);
            retv.setTag(this.inputTag);
            return retv;
        }
    }
    public static class Reduce extends DataJoinReducerBase
    {
        protected TaggedMapOutput combine(Object[] tags, Object[] values)
        {
            if (tags.length < 2) return null;
            String joinedStr = "";
            for (int i=0; i<values.length; i++)
            {
                if (i > 0) joinedStr += ",";
                TaggedWritable tw = (TaggedWritable) values[i];
                String line = ((Text) tw.getData()).toString();
                String[] tokens = line.split(",", 2);
                joinedStr += tokens[1];
            }
            TaggedWritable retv = new TaggedWritable(new Text(joinedStr));
            retv.setTag((Text) tags[0]);
            return retv;
        }
    }
    public static class TaggedWritable extends TaggedMapOutput
    {
        private Writable data;

        public TaggedWritable() {
            this.tag = new Text();
        }

        public TaggedWritable(Writable data)
        {
            this.tag = new Text("");
            this.data = data;
        }

        public Writable getData()
        {
            return data;
        }
        public void write(DataOutput out) throws IOException
        {
            this.tag.write(out);
            this.data.write(out);
        }
        public void readFields(DataInput in) throws IOException
        {
            this.tag.readFields(in);
            this.data.readFields(in);
        }
    }
    public int run(String[] args) throws Exception
    {


        Configuration conf = getConf();
        JobConf job = new JobConf(conf, MultiDataSetJoinMR.class);
        String[] otherArgs = new GenericOptionsParser(conf, args).getRemainingArgs();
        if (otherArgs.length != 2)
        {
            System.err.println("Usage: wordcount <in> <out>");
            System.exit(2);
        }

        Path in = new Path(args[0]);
        Path out = new Path(args[1]);
        FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(job, in);
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, out);
        job.setJobName("DataJoin");
        job.setMapperClass(MapClass.class);
        job.setReducerClass(Reduce.class);
        job.setInputFormat(TextInputFormat.class);
        job.setOutputFormat(TextOutputFormat.class);
        job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(TaggedWritable.class);
        job.set("mapred.textoutputformat.separator", ",");
        JobClient.runJob(job);
        return 0;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        int res = ToolRunner.run(new Configuration(),
                new MultiDataSetJoinMR(),
                args);
        System.exit(res);
    }
}
```

**Running Command**

./hadoop jar MultiDataSetJoin.jar /home/project/dataset /home/project/out

**Error**

But I am facing following issues.

```
15 Mar, 2013 4:29:45 PM org.apache.hadoop.metrics.jvm.JvmMetrics init
INFO: Initializing JVM Metrics with processName=JobTracker, sessionId=
15 Mar, 2013 4:29:45 PM org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient configureCommandLineOptions
WARNING: No job jar file set.  User classes may not be found. See JobConf(Class) or JobConf#setJar(String).
15 Mar, 2013 4:29:45 PM org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat listStatus
INFO: Total input paths to process : 2
15 Mar, 2013 4:29:45 PM org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient monitorAndPrintJob
INFO: Running job: job_local_0001
15 Mar, 2013 4:29:45 PM org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat listStatus
INFO: Total input paths to process : 2
15 Mar, 2013 4:29:45 PM org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask runOldMapper
INFO: numReduceTasks: 1
15 Mar, 2013 4:29:45 PM org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$MapOutputBuffer <init>
INFO: io.sort.mb = 100
15 Mar, 2013 4:29:45 PM org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$MapOutputBuffer <init>
INFO: data buffer = 79691776/99614720
15 Mar, 2013 4:29:45 PM org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$MapOutputBuffer <init>
INFO: record buffer = 262144/327680
15 Mar, 2013 4:29:45 PM org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job run
WARNING: job_local_0001
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error in configuring object
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:93)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:64)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:117)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:354)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:307)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:177)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:88)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error in configuring object
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:93)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:64)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:117)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.configure(MapRunner.java:34)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:88)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at MultiDataSetJoinMR$MapClass.generateInputTag(MultiDataSetJoinMR.java:31)
    at org.apache.hadoop.contrib.utils.join.DataJoinMapperBase.configure(DataJoinMapperBase.java:60)
    ... 18 more
null15 Mar, 2013 4:29:46 PM org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient monitorAndPrintJob
INFO:  map 0% reduce 0%
15 Mar, 2013 4:29:46 PM org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient monitorAndPrintJob
INFO: Job complete: job_local_0001
15 Mar, 2013 4:29:46 PM org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Counters log
INFO: Counters: 0
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Job failed!
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.runJob(JobClient.java:1252)
    at MultiDataSetJoinMR.run(MultiDataSetJoinMR.java:123)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65)
    at MultiDataSetJoinMR.main(MultiDataSetJoinMR.java:128)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
```

From log trace i can identify that inputFile variable gets null value in below method,

```
protected Text generateInputTag(String inputFile)
{
    String datasource = inputFile.split("-")[0];
    return new Text(datasource);
}
```

I dont know from where it gets called and how fix it. Can anyone help me please

Comment: It looks like `generateInputTag` is called by the superclass, `org.apache.hadoop.contrib.utils.join.DataJoinMapperBase`'s `configure()` method.  Try looking in there; it might be that you missed adding something to the Configuration before running.

Comment: Thanks a lot Matt. I checked with that configure method, There also i am getting null pointer exception. For time being i am join the datasets with out DataJoin package.